# How to join fields with different names in Tableau

Tags: database, calculated-columns, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

I have two tables for Tableau with completely different names. For example, one uses `Mickey M Mouse` and the other uses `Mickey the Mouse`.

I know I need some sort of calculated field (maybe?)...but how to I create a relationship with different names?

[image]

Comment: If you are using one of the databases that support using the SPLIT (I know this works with Postgres)  you can create a calculated join as in:  split([Table1]," ",1) = split([Table2]," ",1)

Comment: How many different names will you be working with?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a REPLACE function on the names on Table 2, so the values are replaced as per your definition, and save all the replaced names under a new Calculated Field in Table 2 (eg.  ReplacedNames)

Eg. If Table 2 has "Mickey M Mouse", replace this with "Mickey the Mouse" within Table 2.
You can use a CASE statement in this calculated field and define all your replacement names within it.

Once you have a the new field in Table 2 (ie. ReplacedNames) with the replaced names, you can try joining Table 1 with the new field in Table 2.